# Extract value from array to variable

Tags: php

I'am new in php sorry of my noobing, and have an array, how i can extract phone number(+79999999992) to $var from this array?

```
[profile_settings] => Array
(
  [0] => a:61:{s:9:"user_name";s:5:"shop2";s:10:"user_email";s:16:"shop2@mysite.com";s:10:"first_name";s:0:"";s:9:"last_name";s:0:"";s:10:"store_name";s:7:"Шоп2";s:10:"store_slug";s:5:"shop2";s:11:"store_email";s:16:"shop2@mysite.com";s:5:"phone";s:12:"+79999999992";s:9:"vendor_id";s:5:"99999";s:8:"gravatar";s:0:"";s:11:"banner_type";s:10:"single_img";s:6:"banner";s:0:"";s:12:"banner_video";s:0:"";s:13:"banner_slider";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:4:"link";s:0:"";}}s:13:"mobile_banner";s:0:"";s:16:"list_banner_type";s:10:"single_img";s:11:"list_banner";s:0:"";s:17:"list_banner_video";s:0:"";s:16:"shop_description";s:30:"<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>";s:7:"address";a:6:{s:8:"street_1";s:26:"WallStreet, 10";s:8:"street_2";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:26:"New York";s:3:"zip";s:6:"678790";s:7:"country";s:0:"";s:5:"state";s:12:"Россия";}s:11:"geolocation";a:3:{s:14:"store_location";s:236:"улица WallStreet, New York, New York";s:9:"store_lat";s:10:"67.4629818";s:9:"store_lng";s:11:"153.7092372";}s:19:"store_name_position";s:9:"on_header";s:9:"store_ppp";s:2:"10";s:15:"shipping";a:2:{s:10:"_pt";s:0:"";s:26:"_user_shipping_type";s:0:"";}s:10:"commission";a:8:{s:15:"commission_mode";s:6:"global";s:18:"commission_percent";s:2:"90";s:16:"commission_fixed";s:0:"";s:19:"commission_by_sales";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:5:"sales";s:0:"";s:4:"rule";s:4:"upto";s:4:"type";s:7:"percent";s:10:"commission";s:0:"";s:16:"commission_fixed";s:0:"";}}s:22:"commission_by_products";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:4:"rule";s:4:"upto";s:4:"type";s:7:"percent";s:10:"commission";s:0:"";s:16:"commission_fixed";s:0:"";}}s:22:"commission_by_quantity";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:8:"quantity";s:0:"";s:4:"rule";s:4:"upto";s:4:"type";s:7:"percent";s:10:"commission";s:0:"";s:16:"commission_fixed";s:0:"";}}s:8:"tax_name";s:0:"";s:11:"tax_percent";s:0:"";}s:10:"withdrawal";a:8:{s:16:"transaction_mode";s:6:"global";s:23:"transaction_charge_type";s:2:"no";s:18:"transaction_charge";a:2:{s:3:"cod";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"percent";s:0:"";s:5:"fixed";s:0:"";}}s:15:"offline_gateway";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"percent";s:0:"";s:5:"fixed";s:0:"";}}}s:15:"withdrawal_mode";s:6:"global";s:16:"withdrawal_limit";s:0:"";s:19:"withdrawal_thresold";s:0:"";s:22:"withdrawal_charge_type";s:2:"no";s:17:"withdrawal_charge";a:4:{s:6:"paypal";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:7:"percent";s:0:"";s:5:"fixed";s:0:"";s:3:"tax";s:0:"";}}s:6:"stripe";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:7:"percent";s:0:"";s:5:"fixed";s:0:"";s:3:"tax";s:0:"";}}s:6:"skrill";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:7:"percent";s:0:"";s:5:"fixed";s:0:"";s:3:"tax";s:0:"";}}s:13:"bank_transfer";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:7:"percent";s:0:"";s:5:"fixed";s:0:"";s:3:"tax";s:0:"";}}}}s:7:"payment";a:4:{s:6:"method";s:0:"";s:6:"paypal";a:1:{s:5:"email";s:0:"";}s:6:"skrill";a:1:{s:5:"email";s:0:"";}s:4:"bank";a:8:{s:7:"ac_name";s:0:"";s:9:"ac_number";s:0:"";s:9:"bank_name";s:0:"";s:9:"bank_addr";s:0:"";s:14:"routing_number";s:0:"";s:4:"iban";s:0:"";s:5:"swift";s:0:"";s:4:"ifsc";s:0:"";}}s:16:"store_hours";a:1:{s:9:"day_times";a:7:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"start";s:0:"";s:3:"end";s:0:"";}}i:1;a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"start";s:0:"";s:3:"end";s:0:"";}}i:2;a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"start";s:0:"";s:3:"end";s:0:"";}}i:3;a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"start";s:0:"";s:3:"end";s:0:"";}}i:4;a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"start";s:0:"";s:3:"end";s:0:"";}}i:5;a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"start";s:0:"";s:3:"end";s:0:"";}}i:6;a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"start";s:0:"";s:3:"end";s:0:"";}}}}s:23:"vacation_mode_type";s:7:"instant";s:24:"vacation_start_date";s:0:"";s:22:"vacation_end_date";s:0:"";s:22:"vacation_mode_msg";s:0:"";s:9:"store_seo";a:9:{s:21:"-seo-meta-title";s:0:"";s:20:"-seo-meta-desc";s:0:"";s:24:"-seo-meta-keywords";s:0:"";s:19:"-seo-og-title";s:0:"";s:18:"-seo-og-desc";s:0:"";s:19:"-seo-og-image";s:0:"";s:24:"-seo-twitter-title";s:0:"";s:23:"-seo-twitter-desc";s:0:"";s:24:"-seo-twitter-image";s:0:"";}s:6:"social";a:8:{s:7:"twitter";s:0:"";s:2:"fb";s:0:"";s:9:"instagram";s:0:"";s:7:"youtube";s:0:"";s:8:"linkedin";s:0:"";s:5:"gplus";s:0:"";s:8:"snapchat";s:0:"";s:9:"pinterest";s:0:"";}s:21:"policy_tab_title";s:0:"";s:20:"shipping_policy";s:11:"<p><br></p>";s:18:"refund_policy";s:11:"<p><br></p>";s:24:"cancellation_policy";s:11:"<p><br></p>";s:16:"customer_support";a:8:{s:5:"phone";s:0:"";s:5:"email";s:0:"";s:8:"address1";s:0:"";s:8:"address2";s:0:"";s:7:"country";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:0:"";s:5:"state";s:0:"";s:3:"zip";s:0:"";}s:11:"bfirst_name";s:0:"";s:10:"blast_name";s:0:"";s:6:"bphone";s:0:"";s:7:"baddr_1";s:0:"";s:7:"baddr_2";s:0:"";s:8:"bcountry";s:0:"";s:5:"bcity";s:0:"";s:6:"bstate";s:0:"";s:4:"bzip";s:0:"";s:11:"sfirst_name";s:0:"";s:10:"slast_name";s:0:"";s:7:"saddr_1";s:0:"";s:7:"saddr_2";s:0:"";s:8:"scountry";s:0:"";s:5:"scity";s:0:"";s:6:"sstate";s:0:"";s:4:"szip";s:0:"";s:18:"vacation_mode";s:2:"no";s:30:"disable_vacation_purchase";s:2:"no";s:14:"store_location";s:236:"улица WallStreet, New York, New York";s:9:"store_lat";s:10:"5436";s:9:"store_lng";s:11:"123";}
)
```

Comment: extract(&$array);

Comment: The value of `$profile_settings[0]` looks like a string returned by the PHP function [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). Use [`unserialize($profile_settings[0])`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get the original data structure then use the [square brackets array syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) to access the data inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(unserialise($profile_settings[0])['phone']);
```

Your input is though invalid.

Answer (score 2):

```
$var = [
  'a:61:{s:9:"user_name";s:5:"shop2";s:10:"user_email";s:16:"shop2@mysite.com";s:10:"first_name";s:0:"";s:9:"last_name";s:0:"";s:10:"store_name";s:7:"Шоп2";s:10:"store_slug";s:5:"shop2";s:11:"store_email";s:16:"shop2@mysite.com";s:5:"phone";s:12:"+79999999992";s:9:"vendor_id";s:5:"99999";s:8:"gravatar";s:0:"";s:11:"banner_type";s:10:"single_img";s:6:"banner";s:0:"";...'
];
$new_array = array_map(function($a) {
   return unserialise($a);
}, $var);
```